# Adding comments to Milestone

Tags: entitlements, casemilestone

I want to allow the Service Rep. to allow a comment/description to an entitlement milestone, like what action was performed to meet the milestone.
Example: Milestone is First Response after 15 min from Case creation, the CSR should write in the milestone which channel used to contact the contact person e.g. email/phone and what was communicated.

If there is no such option, is there a good workaround?

Comment: That doesn't sound very practical from the agent point of view, depending on the number of milestones you may have, agents will spend a lot of time completing milestones manually and leaving those comments. Why not auto complete milestones with triggers?

Comment: Ok, but I need to have an option for the agent to add a comment to a milestone....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Case Milestone (a joiner between the Milestone and the specific case record) does not have any note field, and does not allow custom fields to be added.  Because of this, you will not be able to have your Agents add information directly to the case milestone.
What I would suggest is that you have the agent add a comment to the case Comments, and then use a trigger on the CaseComment that ties the specific comment to the active CaseMilestone, and potentially even marks the milestone complete.  I have included some good sample code for you to leverage.

[Trigger Samples](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Auto-completion_of_Case_Milestones_with_Triggers)

[Milestone Utility Class Sample](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Case_Milestones_Utilities_Class)